# merge 2 datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have 2 Datatable dt and dt2

```
 var dt = MultiCheckCombo3.GetAllChechedBox();

 var dt2 =manager.GetAllStudents(student_id, classid);
```

In the first table dt are two columns "id_staff" and "name_staff"
In the second table are several columns but 2 of them repeat "id_staff" and "name_staff"
I want to create a new DataTable with the fields "id_staff" and "name_staff" common DataTable dt and dt2

how joined these tables?
dt3= dt+dt2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq to join the two tables.  See the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx).

Code from the article:

```
var innerGroupJoinQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
    select new { CategoryName = category.Name, Products = prodGroup };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DataTable.Merge` method:

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b.aspx#Y0) from Microsoft has an example of how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("id_staff",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("name_staff",typeof(string));

var dt2=new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("id_staff",typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("name_staff",typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1,"test");
dt2.Rows.Add(2,"test2");

var result= 
(
    from datatable1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
       id_staff=datatable1.Field<int>("id_staff"),
       name_staff=datatable1.Field<string>("name_staff")
    }
).Concat
(
    from datatable2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
       id_staff=datatable2.Field<int>("id_staff"),
       name_staff=datatable2.Field<string>("name_staff")
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If dt and dt2 are DataTables, you can use datatable merge.

```
DataTable dt3 = dt.Copy()
dt3.Merge(dt2, false, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
```